# Why did no US politician start the trade war a decade earlier with China or possibly the Globe if it is a good thing to do?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, international-economics, free-trade, balance-of-trade

Why did no US politician start the trade war with China (or possibly the Globe) a decade earlier if it is a good thing to do?

I am asking for a list of reasons for why not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a question about the motivations of politicians, which is out of scope for this site.

Comment: Who said it's a good thing to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since USA politicians serve shorter terms they have to be concerned with short term popularity.
A trade war could damage possibility of reelection if it takes too long and/or if it damages the USA economy.